# In Eclipse how do you automatically copy a file after save?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I'm a bit of a nOOb in Eclipse, so there may be a way to do this, but I haven't found it.

In other IDEs I have the ability to set up an action to copy a given file to an alternate location upon save.

For example, let's say my repo is in /dev/myproject.  Let's further say that my web root is at /webroot.

When I make a change to /dev/myproject/index.html and save in Eclipse, I would like it then to copy index.html to /webroot/index.html.

Is there a way to do that in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set up a batch file (or whatever) as an [External Tool](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-exttools-running.htm?cp=0_3_14) and set it as a Builder on the project.

Comment: Wouldn't that run only when the project was built, and not upon save?

Comment: True. My bad. I almost always have automatic builds enabled.